# Trouble manually controlling endfloat's ToC and header behavior

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, endfloat

In my thesis, I would like to have

- each figure and table on its own page at the end of each chapter (easy with `endfloat`)
- The first figure of each chapter begins its own section that goes into the ToC, but no section title appears in the actual document.
- same as the previous point, but with tables
- the page header for the figure and table sections reflects the change

Either I end the document with `\processdelayedfloats` and:

- the header correctly changes with the Tables section, but Tables stays in the header into the Figures section
- the ToC shows neither Tables nor Figures.

Or I uncomment the last few lines and:

- the Tables header continues into the new section for 1 page, then changes to the new section
- the ToC gets updated, but the page numbers for Figures and Tables are both the first non-float page.
- `hyperref` links the Figures and Tables ToC entries to neither the page listed nor the first table/figure.

For as awesome the idea of the `endfloat` package is, it seems to be poorly implemented in my opinion. Any help in this problem (as well as understanding how this package works) would be appreciated.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[nolists,nomarkers,noheads,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
%%%%%%%%%%%%% stop endfloat from marking both headers %%%%%%%%%%%%% 
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
        \makeatletter
        \patchcmd{\efloat@process}{\markboth}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}
        \makeatother
    \AtBeginTables{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Tables}\markright{Tables}}
    \AtBeginFigures{\markright{Figures} \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Figures}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{mainMatter}
\makeoddfoot{mainMatter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddhead{mainMatter}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{mainMatter}{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makepsmarks{mainMatter}{%
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{Chapter }{: \ }}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\pagestyle{mainMatter}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{{\HUGE a figure}}
\caption{A Figure placed here}\label{fig:a fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Cool table}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
   A  & 100 \\
   B & 41 \\
   C  & 17 \\
   X?!  & 0 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:my table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{{\HUGE another figure}}
\caption{A Figure placed here}\label{fig:a fig 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{boring table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
A & B \\
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:my table 2}
\end{table}
\lipsum[1]
\processdelayedfloats
\section{Frustrated}
Note that if you uncomment the line below, suddenly the ToC gets updated (incorrectly) and the next page has a new header.
\lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you ever thought of improving endfloat? I'm sure Jeffrey Goldberg would appreciate it. (At least he did when I have improved endfloat.)

Comment: I have no idea how to program TeX. Is there a good resource for learning how? Everything I've done with TeX code has been extremely slow and haphazard (as the example below shows). The solution I found took me hours to work out and I have no idea if it even works in the general case. This was my first time using etoolbox, even.

Comment: Oh, so I got a wrong impression of your skills. It's a pity because Jeffrey does not improve his package anymore and I simply don't even have enough time for my very own packages -- but of course I'm willing to answer questions about implementation details. (If you want to learn TeX, I recommend "TeX by Topic" which you should get by "texdoc texbytopic".)

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what I'm doing, but I figured it out!  The key is to:

- disable the mark both (as in the original MWE)
- enable the `heads` option so `endfloat` tries to load the `\section*` command...
- but first replace the `\section*` command in `endfloat.sty` with `\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@nameuse{#2section}}\markright`

  - the problem I was having with `hyperref` in the ToC is fixed by `\phantomsection`
  - The right header is replaced with `\@nameuse{#2section`, which is either Figures or Tables depending on the floats. without the `heads` option, `endfloat` will skip this part.
- Every figure and table is centered on its page and there are no blank pages before/after the floats thanks to the constant redefining of the default placement (thanks to `\AtBeginTables`, `\AtBeginFigures`, and `\efloatseparator` )
- The last float will occur before any more text as `\processdelayedfloats` now includes a `\FloatBarrier`

  - The inclusion of `\FloatBlock` means this fix requires the `memoir` class. Alternatively, the `placeins` package can be used to substitute `\FloatBarrier` for `\FloatBlock` and (I assume) will have the same result.

Here's the new MWE that does just what I wanted it to do. I hope it's ok to answer one's own question here.

**EDIT** although this fix worked in my MWE, it does not work in my actual document. Maybe it's because some of the captions are long, there are other packages loaded, or I am using `include` to load chapters. For whatever reason, I still have this issue.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[nolists,heads,nomarkers,tablesfirst]{endfloat}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
        \makeatletter
        \patchcmd{\efloat@process}{\markboth}{\@gobbletwo}{}{}
        \patchcmd{\efloat@process}{\section*}{\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@nameuse{#2section}}\markright}{}{}
        \patchcmd{\processdelayedfloats}{\processotherdelayedfloats}{\processotherdelayedfloats\FloatBlock}{}{}
        \makeatother
    \AtBeginTables{\setfloatlocations{table}{h}\null\vfill}
%
    \AtBeginFigures{\setfloatlocations{figure}{h}\null\vfill}

    \AtBeginDelayedFloats{}
    \renewcommand{\efloatseparator}{\vfill\setfloatlocations{table}{p}\setfloatlocations{figure}{p}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\makepagestyle{mainMatter}
\makeoddfoot{mainMatter}{}{\thepage}{}
\makeoddhead{mainMatter}{\leftmark}{}{\rightmark}
\makeheadrule{mainMatter}{\linewidth}{\normalrulethickness}
\makepsmarks{mainMatter}{%
    \nouppercaseheads
    \createmark{section}{right}{nonumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{Chapter }{: \ }}

\usepackage{hyperref}




\begin{document}
\tableofcontents*
\pagestyle{mainMatter}
\chapter{My Chapter}
\section{My Section}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{{\HUGE a figure}}
\caption{A Figure placed here}\label{fig:a fig}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Cool table}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
   A  & 100 \\
   B & 41 \\
   C  & 17 \\
   X?!  & 0 \\
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:my table 1}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\fbox{{\HUGE another figure}}
\caption{A Figure placed here}\label{fig:a fig 2}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{boring table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
A & B \\
    \end{tabular}
  \label{tab:my table 2}
\end{table}



\lipsum[1]
\processdelayedfloats


\section{HURRAY!}
I deserve a beer.
    \lipsum[1-8]

\end{document}
```